# how to make UIbutton draggable within UIView?

Tags: uiview, drag-and-drop, uibutton

I need to drag and drop the button in my dash board i can drag and drop the button using the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
     [eventButton addTarget:self action:@selector(draggedOut:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside |UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
  }

- (void) draggedOut: (UIControl *) c withEvent: (UIEvent *) ev {
       CGPoint point = [[[ev allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    if(point.y > 22 && point.y <300)
            c.center = CGPointMake(237, point.y - c.bounds.size.height/2 -5);
  }
```

but i need while drag and drop i need to change the positions of the buttons too

note:i wrote the code only for one button

please help me for my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [eventButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragOut:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside |UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
   }

-(IBAction)dragOut: (id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
 UIButton *selected = (UIButton *)sender;
 selected.center = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIControlEventTouchDragInside and UIControlEventTouchUpInside events of UIButton like

```
// add drag listener
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
// add tap listener
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(wasTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can use [hbdraggablebutton](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hbdraggablebutton) control..